# Resizing application made by Qt

Tags: qt

I made a program using Qt 5.2.1 . Now when I launch the application and resize it, the scroll bars don't appear automatically.

I have tried adding the scroll area and then within it a widget ( and setting minimum size) but even that doesn't work.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's seems that your problem might not be the issue about the scroll area. Have you tried to add layouts in your widget?

Comment: The scroll area needs to have a layout as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not put a layout in the scroll area's interior. Also, the scroll area itself needs to be inside of a layout.

So you need at least 2 layouts to make this work.

Comment: So I need a layout in the central widget and then add scroll area and then add a layout and then add my other widgets?
Thats a long method... Qt should have added that as a default option

Comment: @user121273 Yes - dialog has layout, inside dialog is a scroll area, scroll area itself has layout, and inside it are your widgets. Did you try it? Did it work for you?

Comment: which one has a size constraint? ( min size?)

Comment: And sadly no... I didn't work
maybe I am doing something wrong... I'll try a few more times and get back here

Comment: I uploaded an [example project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9PGUhmmnsm1SnRBNDVYOG1LRGs/edit?pli=1). Download it, and see how it works. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanx a lot man, your project works... I'll study it and try to find out what I was doing wrong.... Thanx a ton man!

Comment: your project works just fine but mine doesn't 
(https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2JQ4rR_-sjmMGRqQno2UXpOSWc&usp=sharing) this is a project I am trying this on. please take a look.